# Django - how do I clone object without applying clone changes to source object

Tags: python, django

Best described by example:

View:

```
def my_view(request):
    obj_old = Inventories.objects.get(id = source_id)
    obj_new = obj_old 
    obj_old.some_field = 0
    obj_old.save()

    obj_new.some_field = 1
    obj_new.id = None
    obj_new.save()
```

The problem is that the changes I make to obj_new are also applied to `obj_old` so that the value of `some_field` is 1 for both `obj_old` and `obj_new`. Any ideas how to fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make a *copy* of your object, and not make them equal.

To make a copy you can use the copy module

```
import copy

obj_new = copy.deepcopy(obj_old)
```